# Are there some caveats for using guids for FB comments

Tags: comments, facebook, guids

I'm using Facebook comments box and just realized that when we use
`<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>` and then realize our title is wrong, changing the title (and slug in the process) we lose all social counts because they are tied to the url.

So I was wondering why I'm not using
`<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_guid(); ?>" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>` instead.

The url as `domain.com/?p=10000` doesn't change even if the slug/url or what ever would change.

Are there some caveats for this method I'm not realizing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `301 redirect` the old URLs. This can be done by using `Custom Permalinks` plugin which automatically updates the 301 version of the URL and thus helping the Facebook plugin to recognise and restore the likes and comments.

Comment: Yeah if I change on the fly, that's true. But let's assume I'm starting a whole new site for example, is it ok to be using the guid instead of the "pretty" permalink?